How to input derivatives in LaTeX form to Mathematica expression?
I'm trying to use the 'TeX Math Formula' feature in Mathematica notebook with the following:
$\mu_d \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{d r}\left(r \frac{d u_d}{d r}\right) = \frac{d p}{d z} + \rho_d g$

However, I get the error:
Syntax: Incomplete expression; more input is needed. 

I wonder what would be the right way to input derivatives in LaTeX form in a way that Mathematica would recognize them? The goal is to solve the ODE symbolically using appropriate boundary conditions eventually.

203037 is related, though not particularly helpful. This seems like it's somewhat hard to answer without writing some sort of parser..
